# Failed Audit Regarding Non-Programming Software

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6616123) in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491617/chrome-opera-blink-painting-issue).

I marked the question as `off-topic` -> `about general computing hardware and software`. In my opinion, questions about (potentially) buggy browser rendering engines are wildly off-topic on Stack Overflow as there isn't the possibility of a helpful answer.

Of course, this assumes that it actually IS a buggy rendering engine, which is pre-supposed in the question. There is no accepted answer - one of which is a Javascript solution and one of which is a CSS solution - and both appear to be work-arounds for the buggy engine.

As I said, it's my opinion that this is cut-and-dry off-topic (though definitely a candidate for other SE sites).

Can anyone explain how I'm wrong?

Comment: As that question is phrased, I agree, but I think there's an implied "How do I work around this in the web application I'm developing?" that's as on-topic as other questions about webapp development.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I think I understand and agree. In this situation, is it better to suggest edits, close and wait for edits to reopen, or something else? Obviously the community decided to keep it open, but is there a more thorough solution?

Comment: You're >2k, so you don't have to _suggest_ edits.  For a question like this one with an obvious implied question, I'd just make the edit.